# Another way of getting n(A ∪ B ∪ C)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm trying to find n(A ∪ B ∪ C) using this formula:
n(A ∪ B ∪ C) = n(A) + n(B) + n(C) - n(A ∩ B) − n(A ∩ C) − n(B ∩ C) + n(A ∩ B ∩ C)

But n(B ∩ C) is not included in the given.

Since there is a given n(A ∪ B ∪ C)' and n(Ω), can the equation below be used?

**n(A ∪ B ∪ C) = n(Ω) - n(A ∪ B ∪ C)'**

Comment: Yes, that equation is valid.  Note that $(A \cup B \cup C)' = A' \cap B' \cap C'$.

Comment: Yes, it is correct.